# Le mot « dérivation » pour décrire les étapes suivies pour démontrer une formule mathématique?

Tags: vocabulaire, mathématiques

Je suis en train d'écrire ma thèse de doctorat, elle contient plusieurs  formules mathématiques proposées.

Dans l'article publié et qui est bien sûr en anglais, par exemple la phrase **"The detailed derivation of this formula is discussed in Appendix A.2."**
est plus utilisée et semble correcte du point de vue vocabulaire.

En français j'ai utilisé **"La dérivation détaillée de cette formule est présentée dans l'annexe A.2".** À l'étape de la correction de ma thèse, mon directeur de thèse m'a dit que le mot **"dérivation"** est incorrect et il faut le remplacer par **"développement"** parce que le mot « dérivation » concerne des dérivées (g').

Quel est le mot correct pour décrire les étapes suivies afin d'avoir l'expression finale d'une formule mathématique ?

Comment: Tu parles de dérivations formelles avec des règles d'inférence, ou de mathématiques plus habituelles ?

Comment: Je parle de dérivations formalles

Comment: Dans ce cas, « dérivation » ou « arbre de dérivation » sont des termes employés fréquemment. Un exemple parmi d'autres: https://www.lri.fr/~paulin/MathInfo/html/cours003.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

« Dérivation » n'est pas incorrect du point de vue sémantique, ce serait même un mot très approprié si ce n'était pour le sens aussi très important qui lui est donné dans le calcul différentiel. Le mot « développement » me semble convenir mais il caractérise plutôt la présentation des étapes dans l'obtention de la formule finale et  plutôt un choix des étapes intermédiaires. Un terme préférable, il me semble, est « déduction »; on pourrait donc dire

> « La déduction détaillée de cette formule est présentée dans l'annexe A.2 ».

Une autre possibilité

> « Les manipulations détaillées de la déduction de cette formule sont présentées dans l'annexe A.2 »

Selon cette façon de voir, on peut concevoir  que plusieurs développements  correspondent à une unique déduction.  On ne peut plus parler alors pour une méthode donnée de déduction que de **la** déduction de la formule (la déduction de la formule par tel moyen); cependant, c'est une façon de voir qui n'est pas reconnue, elle implique une spécialisation des termes qui reste à forcer.

> - (TLFi) a) MATH. Déduction (mathématique). ,,Démonstration mathématique traditionnelle qui conduit des principes aux conséquences (...) par opposition au raisonnement expérimental qui reconduit aux lois à partir des faits` (LEGRAND 1972)
>     ... c'est à l'aide de la déduction que nous descendons du principe général (axiomes) au cas particulier (théorème), sans avoir besoin d'aucune expérience.
>     b) LOG. ,,Type de raisonnement qui conduit de une ou plusieurs propositions dites prémisses, à une conclusion « nécessaire », c'est-à-dire inévitable si l'on accepte la règle du jeu (LEGRAND 1972). Déduction logique, syllogistique.

Comment: « déduction de cette formule » ne semble pas très correcte. Elle n'est pas présente sur google http://google.com/search?q=déduction+formule

Comment: @Paracosmiste  Je ne sais pas trop jusqu'où on peut aller avec Google pour infirmer ou justifier quoi  que ce soit en matière d'usage mais je crois pouvoir me fier à ceci (je vais d'ailleurs l'ajouter à ma réponse) : (TLFi) a) MATH. Déduction (mathématique). ,,Démonstration mathématique traditionnelle qui conduit des principes aux conséquences (...) par opposition au raisonnement expérimental qui reconduit aux lois à partir des faits`` (LEGRAND 1972) :

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Pour passer d'une égalité à une autre on a le choix de donner entre les deux ou d'ignorer, des égalités qui découlent de la première mais qui sont plus ou moins simples de sorte que l'on peut les calculer de tête, sinon leu lecteur,  s'il veut vraiment les vérifier, les déduira stylo en main; ce sont les étapes intermédiaires; la présentation c'est la façon de disposer les égalités ( et inégalités) sur la page et c'est la façon de noter ces éléments, par exemple en utilisant plus ou moins de termes (notation); au lieu de « x1 + x2+…+xn » la forme « x1 +…+xn » (champ 1)

Comment: @Survenant9r7 ce qui revient à signifier la même chose. La déduction, pour définir cela du point de vue mathématique ou logique d'une autre manière que dans les définitions du dictionnaire, c'est le passage de faits connus à un fait jusqu'alors inconnu comme étant une vérité, au moyen d'une série de faits connus (les axiomes, théorèmes et définitions); (champ 2)

Comment: @Survenant9r7 dans la vie de tous les jours ça revient à cet exemple-cii: les gens fument trop; ils n'ont pas beaucoup d'argent, les prix hauts les décourage ; si on augmente le prix les gens fument moins (pas d'argent); donc ils sont moins malades (moins de tabac préserve la santé); donc la sécurité sociale a une charge moins grande (la dépense médicale incombe à cet organisme), donc les gens débourse moins pour maintenir l'organisme en opération. Ceci est la déduction  de « augmenter le prix du tabac réduit les charges de la société dans l'ensemble.» (champ 3)

Comment: @Survenant9r7 En gros ce n'est pas autre chose, la déduction. Dans ma réponse il ne s'agit pas de forcer un point de vue en ce qui concerne la déduction, concept qui reste ce qu'il est, mais de changer la signification de « développement » ou plutôt de la préciser de façon à ne pas en faire un synonyme de déduction, et donc plutôt de lui donner le sens de présentation donnée d'une déduction, en particulier celle d'une formule. Les étapes font partie du processus de déduction; c'est tout le processus de déduction qui passe en annexe, (champ 4)

Comment: @Survenant9r7  où évidemment on recopie la formule elle-même. Le développement c'est l'ensemble des étapes, c'est aussi l'acte d'écrire ces étapes (par exemple, « Dans votre développement de la formule vous avez oublié la constante c.» est une phrase correcte.). Cependant, je ne crois pas que l'on associe le terme spécifiquement avec l'idée de déduction mathématique ((TLFi) ALG. Développement d'une fonction (en série), d'une série, d'une expression algébrique. ), d'où mon idée de l'en écarter clairement (en forçant une définition plus spécifique). (fin)

Comment: Je comprends ton analogie mais elle est boiteuse. Par ailleurs ce que tu expliques est fort peu accessible. Merci cependant d'avoir pris le temps d'expliquer.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Ça ne peut pas être, bien sûr, la fine analyse d'un gouvernement français qui cherche à enrayer le petit fléau national du tabagisme ; ce n'est que la chose dans ses grandes lignes (qui nous suffisent pour la discussion en fait) pour montrer que la version mathématique ne renferme rien de plus (sauf des particularités).

Answer (score 4):

> « La démonstration détaillée de cette formule est présentée dans l'annexe A.2. »

Ou plus simplement (et à mon avis plus naturellement, en français) :

> « Cette formule est démontrée dans l'annexe A.2. »

Comment: En effet, excepté le cas particulier des systèmes de preuve formels, ces formulations sont de loin les plus habituelles.

Answer (score 3):

Ton directeur de thèse a raison, *dérivation* concerne les dérivées et *développement* est plus approprié dans ce contexte.

Comment: Oui je suis du même avis que @Toto. Si malgré tout vous tenez à obtenir d'autres expressions voisines j'ajouterai **Démonstration** et **Étude**